# What's wrong with my code snippet?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a code snippet that's giving me some slightly annoying problems. Here's the snippet:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
    <CodeSnippets  
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">  
<CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">  
    <Header>  
        <Title>Set With Notify</Title>
        <Description>Code snippet for common model setters</Description>
        <Shortcut>notify_member</Shortcut>  
    </Header>  
    <Snippet>
        <Declarations>
            <Literal>
                <ID>type</ID>
                <ToolTip>The type of both members</ToolTip>
            </Literal>
            <Literal>
                <ID>member</ID>
                <ToolTip>The member symbol</ToolTip>
            </Literal>
        </Declarations>

        <Code Language="CSharp">  
            <![CDATA[
    private $type$ _$member$;
    public $type$ $member$
    {
        get 
        {
            return _$member$;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != this._$member$)
            {
                this._$member$ = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
            ]]>  
        </Code>  
    </Snippet>  
</CodeSnippet>
```

So, first issue I've already worked around but it made my snippet slightly more difficult to use: When using only 2 Declarations/Replacements the snippet would just get pasted into the editor without an opportunity to specify type, or member.

Currently, whenever I use this snippet, the two braces following my set function are not properly indented. The final brace is in the right spot and all other code is indented correctly.

So, what am I missing or doing improperly to cause this formatting issue?

Comment: Ensure you haven't mixed tabs and spaces for indentation.

Comment: I edited the snippet by removing all indents and then moved over everything with tabs and it actually made the formatting even worse some how.